# Tools to monitor users activity on Linux/Unix servers

Tags: linux, security, audit

Is there any specific open source tool which can be used to monitor what users are doing on linux system. I have multiple servers and with access to some users on them. I want to  monitor which user ran which commands at what time. I want it to be monitored from Centralized server. 
I know about tripwire,sysstat. But those are not full filling my requirements.

Please suggest.

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check OSSEC,

It can do file integrity checks, besides it can monitor syslog/audit.log and forward it to centralize OSSEC server, and if you write correct rules even notify you when user runs something wrong. (or block this user/ip)

Comment: can we track from which ip which user is connected and what he has done ?

Answer (score 1):

Linux comes with the auditd system. It allows the monitoring of what you require. Look at this [question](https://serverfault.com/q/202044/6543).

And like iscsi said, you could set up log forwarding to your central server.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup audit log forwarding.